# Merging merged querybuilders in laravel 5.2 to then paginate

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a product class with two category ids specified in it. I have the following relations set up and now I'm wanting to paginate the `products` result set.

```
public function productsWithFirstCategory()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Entities\Product', 'category1_id');
}

public function productsWithSecondCategory()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Entities\Product', 'category2_id');
}

public function products()
{
    return $this->productsWithFirstCategory->merge($this->productsWithSecondCategory);
}

public function getProductsPaginatedAttribute()
{
    return $this->products()->paginate(20);
}
```

It appears I can't paginate the results because the merge does not return a query builder - how do I paginate a merged result set?

Answer (score 1):

When you do **$this->productsWithFirstCategory**, you're accessing the result collection instead of the query builders, while **paginate()** can only work on **query builders** in your scenario.

In order to get what you need, you'll need to do a **union** of 2 queries. Just replace your **products()** method with:

```
public function products()
{
  return $this->productsWithFirstCategory()->union($this->productsWithSecondCategory());
}
```

This will return the union of 2 query builders that you can later paginate in your **getProductsPaginatedAttribute()** method.

Comment: Although `$item->products` successfully lists the products, when I try to paginate them I get the error message - `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 SELECTs to the left and right of UNION do not have the same number of result columns (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from "products" where "products"."category1_id" = 1 and "products"."category1_id" is not null union select * from "products" where "products"."category2_id" = 1 and "products"."category2_id" is not null)`

Comment: further researach shows that the raw sql works if no count is fetched though

Comment: It seems that Eloquent does not handle union queries correctly when it comes to counting the resutls - the query that is generated is incorrect for MySQL at least. What you could do is creating the paginator yourself, but it would require fetching all the pages of results every time you need to fetch a simple page. It could work if you don't have too many pages - is that ok for you?

Comment: for now i've just done a manual query in products() pulling where category1_id = $id or where category2_id = $id;